# How to get Azure DevOps project Created Date?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

How to get Project Creation Date in Azure DevOps? using Azure DevOps REST API?

When I try to get the project created date using Azure DevOps REST API.

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}?includeCapabilities={includeCapabilities}&includeHistory={includeHistory}&api-version=7.1-preview.4](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/projects/%7BprojectId%7D?includeCapabilities=%7BincludeCapabilities%7D&includeHistory=%7BincludeHistory%7D&api-version=7.1-preview.4)

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}/properties?api-version=7.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/properties?api-version=7.1-preview.1)

I tried above 2 REST API's; the response is not having project created date.
is there any way to get the Azure DevOps project created date.

Please help me to find out a solution.

Comment: Usually its best to show some code and your attempt. Just saying

Answer (score 0):

There is no Azure DevOps API/CLI can return the created date of project.

If you really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

Comment: @AmalRavindran, Is the answer helpful for you? And is there any response from you?